# css div center alignment

Tags: html, css

I want to position a set of div container in the center of a page.

The div contains a title, and an image. the outer div has a border, and i want to align the image title as well as the image itself to position to the center of the outer div.
as a reference here is link

```css
  #container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  .menuicon {
    align-self: flex-start;
    border: 2px solid #808080;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 4px;
    border-radius: 10px;
  }
  div.spacer {
    clear: both;
  }
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="spacer">
    &nbsp;
  </div>
  <div class="menuicon">
    <p>Image Header Title</p>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="image1.png" width="100" />
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="menuicon">
    <p>Title</p>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="image2.png" width="100" />
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="menuicon">
    <p>Longer Image Header Title</p>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="image3.png" width="100" />
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="spacer">
    &nbsp;
  </div>
</div>
```

so, in case of 1st, 3rd the image should fit to the center, because of wider image title, but in case of 2nd the title should positioned to the center relative to the image width

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use `text-align:center;` on `menuicon`

```
.menuicon
  {
    align-self: flex-start;
    border: 2px solid #808080 ;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 4px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    text-align:center; /* <--- this */
  }
```

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/59L8gqtc/6/)

As far as alignment overall to the viewport, you also have the `width` of `container` set to `1000px`, [**removing this will center to the viewport**](http://jsfiddle.net/59L8gqtc/7/)

Comment: thanks! that seems really simple, but after those sooo many trials, i couldn't imagine that text-align will position image as well.

Answer (score 0):

Give .menuicon text-align: center it will work. Or just copy the code.

```
      #container {
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        justify-content: center;
        width: 1000px;
        margin: 0 auto;
      }
      .menuicon {
        align-self: flex-start;
        border: 2px solid #808080;
        margin: 10px;
        padding: 4px;
        border-radius: 10px;
text-align: center;
      }
      div.spacer {
        clear: both;
      }

<!-- language: lang-html -->

    <div id="container">
      <div class="spacer">
        &nbsp;
      </div>
      <div class="menuicon">
        <p>Image Header Title</p>
        <a href="#">
          <img src="image1.png" width="100" />
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="menuicon">
        <p>Title</p>
        <a href="#">
          <img src="image2.png" width="100" />
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="menuicon">
        <p>Longer Image Header Title</p>
        <a href="#">
          <img src="image3.png" width="100" />
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="spacer">
        &nbsp;
      </div>
    </div>

<!-- end snippet -->
```